# How to use DNS-over-TLS with BIND9 forwarders

Tags: dns, bind9

BIND9 v9.18 improves support for DNS-over-TLS (DoT) and DNS-over-HTTPS (DoH). However, while the [docs](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9_18_11/) explain how to use TLS for the server part, it does not reveal how to enable DNS-over-TLS for query forwarding. Does BIND9 v9.18 support it?

How does the config snippet need to be tweaked to use DoT for the forwarders?

```
options {
        […]
        forwarders {
                // Forward to Cloudflare public DNS resolver
                1.1.1.1;
                1.0.0.1;
        };
        […]
}
```

Simply adding `port 853` and expecting some magic to happen does not seem to be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is the top hit on Google for configuring BIND9 to forward via DNS-over-TLS, here's how I've configured and tested on BIND 9.19.13, connecting to OpenDNS.

I created a `named.conf.dot` in `/etc/bind/` and referenced it via an include, but you could just as easily add this directly to `named.conf`

```
tls OpenDNS-DoT {
    ca-file "/etc/ssl/certs/IdenTrust_Commercial_Root_CA_1.pem";
    remote-hostname "dns.opendns.com";
};

    options {

    forwarders port 853 tls OpenDNS-DoT {

            // OpenDNS public
            208.67.222.222;
            208.67.220.220;
    };

};
```

According to Aram at ISC, [this feature](https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/merge_requests/7199) will be included in the next stable release, 9.20.

Comment: After installing BIND9 v9.19 from the [Debian experimental](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianExperimental) branch, I can confirm that the configuration works as desired. Thank you!

Comment: @esowash Does port 853 need to be open? I have opened mine but when I look at my traffic, nothing goes through 853...only 53

Comment: It does. Do you have another .conf referenced that wants to use 53?

Comment: @esowash if you are accepting queries on port 853 then would you not need a certificate for the server and not just for 1.1.1.1?

Comment: @esowash Also you would need BIND9 to listen on port 853 as well no?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [indicates that the `forwarders` statement grammar has been extended](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#namedconf-statement-forwarders) to:

```
forwarders [ port <integer> ] [ tls <string> ] { ( <ipv4_address> | <ipv6_address> ) [ port <integer> ] [ tls <string> ]; ... };
```

Note that the `tls <string>` part refers to a separate `tls` statement block.

I have not tested this, but based on the documentation, it looks like you might need a snippet like this:

```
tls cloudflare-DoT {
    ca-file "/some/where/ca-certs-applicable-for-cloudflare.pem";
    // currently Cloudflare uses "DigiCert TLS Hybrid ECC SHA384 2020 CA1" as CA
    dhparam-file "/some/where/dhparam.pem";
    remote-hostname "one.one.one.one";
    ciphers "HIGH:!kRSA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS:!SHA1:!SHA256:!SHA384"; // or whatever you consider acceptable
    prefer-server-ciphers yes;
    session-tickets no;
};
options {
    forwarders port 853 tls cloudflare-DoT {
        1.1.1.1;
        1.0.0.1; //yes, this also returns a certificate with hostname "one.one.one.one".
    };
};
```

The `dhparam.pem` file can be created with:

```
openssl dhparam -out /path/to/dhparam.pem <3072_or_4096>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. There's a difference in the documentation for [v9.18.11](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9_18_11/reference.html#namedconf-statement-forwarders) and the upcoming [next release](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#namedconf-statement-forwarders). Only the latter documents TLS for forwarders. And indeed, trying to configure TLS forwarders for v9.18 results in error.