# How to test if DNS over TLS (DoT) with BIND9 forwarders is actually working?

Tags: linux, dns, bind

I am using DNS over TLS with BIND9 forwarders using the answer from this questions: [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/749164)

I can see queries being made successfully but how can I check to see if the queries are using DoT or are they just standard TCP/UDP queries?

Answer (score 0):

If lazy, I'd just use `tcpdump` (which can do more than just dump TCP) to filter for outgoing UDP packets to port 53, and TCP packets to ports 53 and 853. If a request triggers traffic on 853, it's being resolved through DoT.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the dnslookup utility: https://github.com/ameshkov/dnslookup

For testing with a DoT query:

```
dnslookup example.org tls://your_dns_server
```